# Inmediate inicialization of ROS when turning on the robot

Tags: ros, quadcopter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I want to build a Quadrotor robot with an IntensePC on it so I it can be programmed with ROS in order to perform autonomous navigation etc. The thing is that I want that robot to initialize inmediatly without starting ubuntu etc. like when you turn on a cellphone or an old fashined nintendo console, you push the ON button and in a few seconds it is up and running the main program.

Is it possible to do this with ROS?

and if yes. How can I do it?

Thank you all!!

Oscar Rodrigo Hernández Panczenko

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43804/inmediate-inicialization-of-ros-when-turning-on-the-robot./) by [Oscar_Panczenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/3204/oscar_panczenko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I designed the package [ros_comm_upstart](https://github.com/laas/ros_comm_upstart) specifically for this goal.
It wraps `roscore` as a service that can be launched at startup.

It is available as a [Debian package](https://github.com/downloads/laas/ros_comm_upstart/ros-electric-ros-comm-upstart_0.1_all.deb) for ROS Electric. It would not be difficult to adapt this work for Fuerte.

It is also possible to adapt this work to make it launch a ROS launch file at start-up.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.

"Without starting Ubuntu" is vague. I'll assume that you mean "without starting a graphical interface or logging in"

This is quite possible and relatively easy; you'll want to make a single launch file that brings up all of the ROS nodes for your robot, and create an upstart script that runs that launch file. This is how the Turtlebot is configured.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-09-13**:
The code which the TurtleBot uses can be found here: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_bringup/upstart